# Concat dataframes with different date format

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames:

```
df1 = 

             val1       val2
date
2020-01-01  42.353719   34.823934
2020-01-02  42.255172   34.683523
2020-01-03  46.049281   37.036076
2020-01-04  41.026087   36.340164
2020-01-05  32.300000   18.835484


df2 = 

                                val3       val4
date
2020-01-01 01:00:00+01:00       4021.28    570.06
2020-01-01 02:00:00+01:00       4149.82    842.25
2020-01-01 03:00:00+01:00       4307.65    1638.57
2020-01-02 04:00:00+01:00       4428.95    2109.98
2020-01-02 05:00:00+01:00       4542.47    2365.25
2020-01-02 05:00:00+01:00       4462.47    2325.25
...
```

I would then like the `val1` and `val2` from `df1` to be inserted for all rows with the same date (they don't have the same date format of course) in `df2`, i.e.:

```
df_final = 

                                val1        val2        val3       val4
date
2020-01-01 01:00:00+01:00       42.353719   34.823934   4021.28    570.06
2020-01-01 02:00:00+01:00       42.353719   34.823934   4149.82    842.25
2020-01-01 03:00:00+01:00       42.353719   34.823934   4307.65    1638.57
2020-01-02 04:00:00+01:00       42.255172   34.683523   4428.95    2109.98
2020-01-02 05:00:00+01:00       42.255172   34.683523   4542.47    2365.25
2020-01-02 05:00:00+01:00       42.255172   34.683523   4462.47    2325.25
```

How can this be done?

Comment: you might just need to convert the datetime to date and the combine. like this `df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.date`

Comment: The thing is I need the datetime.

Comment: you can create a new column say 'datem' that you use for the merge, the original datetime remains.

Comment: @DenverDang if any of the two answers solve your question, please consider closing the question by accepting one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is straightforward but here is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
df1["Date_merge"] = df1.index.date

df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
df2["Date_merge"] = df2.index.date

df_final = (
    df1.merge(df2, on="Date_merge")
    .set_index(df2.index)
    .rename_axis("date")
    .drop("Date_merge", axis=1)
)
print(df_final)

                                 val1        val2      val3       val4
date                
2020-01-01 01:00:00+01:00   42.353719   34.823934   4021.28     570.06
2020-01-01 02:00:00+01:00   42.353719   34.823934   4149.82     842.25
2020-01-01 03:00:00+01:00   42.353719   34.823934   4307.65     1638.57
2020-01-02 04:00:00+01:00   42.255172   34.683523   4428.95     2109.98
2020-01-02 05:00:00+01:00   42.255172   34.683523   4462.47     2325.25
```

If someone wants to reconstruct the data, here `df1` & `df2` I made by the given tables:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "val1": {
            "2020-01-01": 42.353719,
            "2020-01-02": 42.255172,
            "2020-01-03": 46.049281,
            "2020-01-04": 41.026087,
            "2020-01-05": 32.3,
        },
        "val2": {
            "2020-01-01": 34.823934,
            "2020-01-02": 34.683523,
            "2020-01-03": 37.036076,
            "2020-01-04": 36.340164,
            "2020-01-05": 18.835484,
        },
    }
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "val3": {
            "2020-01-01 01:00:00+01:00": 4021.28,
            "2020-01-01 02:00:00+01:00": 4149.82,
            "2020-01-01 03:00:00+01:00": 4307.65,
            "2020-01-02 04:00:00+01:00": 4428.95,
            "2020-01-02 05:00:00+01:00": 4462.47,
        },
        "val4": {
            "2020-01-01 01:00:00+01:00": 570.06,
            "2020-01-01 02:00:00+01:00": 842.25,
            "2020-01-01 03:00:00+01:00": 1638.57,
            "2020-01-02 04:00:00+01:00": 2109.98,
            "2020-01-02 05:00:00+01:00": 2325.25,
        },
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion. You create a new helper column called 'datem' which is the date without the time. Then use this column for the merge process.

See the script.

```
import pandas as pd
import io   

df1="""date   val1   val2
2020-01-01   42.353719   34.823934
2020-01-02   42.255172   34.683523
2020-01-03   46.049281   37.036076
2020-01-04   41.026087   36.340164
2020-01-05   32.300000   18.835484
"""
df2="""date   val3   val4
2020-01-01 01:00:00+01:00   4021.28   570.06
2020-01-01 02:00:00+01:00   4149.82   842.25
2020-01-01 03:00:00+01:00   4307.65   1638.57
2020-01-02 04:00:00+01:00   4428.95   2109.98
2020-01-02 05:00:00+01:00   4542.47   2365.25
2020-01-02 05:00:00+01:00   4462.47   2325.25
"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df1), sep="   ",engine='python')
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')


df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df2), sep="   ",engine='python')
df2['date'] = df2['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df2['datem'] = df2['date'].dt.floor('d') ##helper column for the merge.
df1.merge(df2,left_on=['date'],right_on=['datem'])
```

Result is here:

```
date_x  val1    val2    date_y  val3    val4    datem
0   2020-01-01  42.353719   34.823934   2020-01-01 00:00:00 4021.28 570.06  2020-01-01
1   2020-01-01  42.353719   34.823934   2020-01-01 01:00:00 4149.82 842.25  2020-01-01
2   2020-01-01  42.353719   34.823934   2020-01-01 02:00:00 4307.65 1638.57 2020-01-01
3   2020-01-02  42.255172   34.683523   2020-01-02 03:00:00 4428.95 2109.98 2020-01-02
4   2020-01-02  42.255172   34.683523   2020-01-02 04:00:00 4542.47 2365.25 2020-01-02
5   2020-01-02  42.255172   34.683523   2020-01-02 04:00:00 4462.47 2325.25 2020-01-02
```

Let me know what you think.